# CORS configuration stopped working all of a sudden

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors

I have an application deployed to google cloud (java 11/ spring, classic stack) for over a year and a half (feb 2020) and it worked flawlessly until now.

I had CORS configured like this

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);

        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*")); // bad practice i know
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source), new ServletRegistrationBean[0]);
        bean.setOrder(-2147483648);
        return bean;
    }
```

And frontend is hosted on firebase.

Since year and half nobody redeployed anything, but it started throwing CORS errors just now.

Is there some update google cloud / some policy I missed that it stopped working all of a sudden? Tried on EDGE and CHrome, as well as Safari, so it should not be browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay nevermind, so I found out that the BILLING ACCOUNT has expired somehow. Then the server was turned off and in that case you get this weird CORS error.